# How do I make nav menu slide in from the side on small screens in Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've got a pretty normal layout, with navigation in a sidebar to the left, and main content to the right of that. And the way Bootstrap works is that when the screen is too narrow for that, the navigation menu comes at the top, and the content below that.

But I find that extremely ugly. I don't want to waste that much space on navigation when I have actual content to show. What I want instead is to have a very narrow bar or button of the left side, and when you touch it, a modal navigation menu slides out from the left.

I can't find anything about how to accomplish that in bootstrap. No examples or tutorials, but also no other docs.

Some issues I encountered: when I do it as part of the grid, it flows to the top at small screens, and I obviously don't want that. When I make it part of the main content, it gets too far from the edge of the screen; I want it right at the edge of the screen. Also, it scrolls with the main content, and I want it to stay where it is. Absolute positioning, I guess.

And then there's the issue that this should only happen on small screens. On large screens, the way it is now is perfect. So the sidebar that's normally visible on a large screen should be hidden and slide in as a modal on a small screen. And I haven't even seen any sideways sliding or collapsing components.

So how do you do this? Is it possible at all in Bootstrap?

Answer (score 2):

Without any plugin you can do like this.

https://jsfiddle.net/syamacl45/mcekfnpt/

```
$('[data-toggle="slide-collapse"]').on('click', function() {
    $navMenuCont = $($(this).data('target'));
    $navMenuCont.animate({
        'width': 'toggle'
    }, 350);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is indeed possible.  There is a jQuery Plugin called jPanelMenu:

http://jpanelmenu.com/

It is open source and on github!

Hope this helps!

Comment: The media queries aren't the issue here, it's the sliding sideways. I do have a kind of solution for that, but it's not terribly pretty yet. I was planning to look into jQuery Mobile to see if that had any nice solutions for this.

Comment: I totally understand what you are trying to accomplish.  For example, like this site: http://foodsense.is/   <-- Media Queries   You can have the navigation be a drop down menu, or, whatever you desire really. It's much simpler than a jQuery solution (well, at least for me) and definitely faster than jQuery Mobile. But, if you want to, you can combine jQuery with media queries to target the exact result you desire.  Btw, bootstrap already has a media query causing your navigation to do what it does.  Just to see what I'm talking about, go to your nav div and put an ID of "query-test"

Comment: Then go to the media query for smaller viewports, and use #query-test {display:none;}  The menu will disappear on smaller viewports.  Then you can create a WHOLE NEW menu design for mobile that you love, and do the opposite:  #nav-menu-for-mobile {display:block;}.  If this doesn't make sense to you yet, let me know and I will explain better.  Anyway, I am working on the same goal myself, responsive design, and to me, this is the way to do it.

Comment: See this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14832894/twitter-bootstrap-non-responsive-row-in-responsive-layout/14833125#14833125

Comment: They're nice general Bootstrap examples, but neither has the sideways sliding menu I'm looking for. I'll have a good look at that stackoverflow question. It's not what I'm talking about, but it looks interesting nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an off-canvas menu like shown in this example: http://bootply.com/94838

When the browser width is narrow, the sidebar collapses and can be expanded by clicking the arrow on the left side.