# Twitter Bootstrap: non-responsive row in responsive layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a responsive fluid grid system on my site, and in most cases the responsive Bootstrap behaviour is what I want: on small screens, the grid columns become fluid and stack vertically.

However, using grid nesting, inside a nested row this is not always the desired behaviour. There are some rows that are not supposed to be stacked vertically, regardless how small the screen is. This is exactly the behaviour of the whole grid when I completely disable all responsive CSS code, but obviously this is no alternative if the responsive behaviour is required for the outer rows.

The relevant markup is:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span6">This column should be stacked on small devices.</div>
        <div class="span6">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span6">Nested row. This column should NOT be stacked on small devices.</div>
                <div class="span6">Nested row. This column should NOT be stacked on small devices.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See this [jsfidde](http://jsfiddle.net/m4r73n/VzNRH/2/) for clarification.

How would one best solve this problem? Is there a way to do it with the native bootstrap functions?

Comment: I think that in your second span6 div you should have two span3 divs - not another two span6 divs.

Comment: BillyMoat: I don't think so, see http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem (Fluid Nesting).

Comment: I stand corrected :-) The fluid one is different to the static one - I didn't realise that as I haven't used a fluid Bootstrap design yet.

Answer (score 3):

```
[class*="span"] .span6 { display: inline-block; width: 48.61878453038674%}
```

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/NfTQ7/1/

Answer (score 0):

What I have done to solve issues like this is the following:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div id="remove-mobile" class="span6">Nested row. This column should NOT be stacked on small devices.</div>
    <div id="remove-mobile" class="span6">Nested row. This column should NOT be stacked on small devices.</div>
</div>


@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {

    #remove-mobile {

        display:none;

    }

}
```

That way, you get rid of that whole mess on smaller devices, and you can add code specifically targeted towards mobile sizes by simply doing the opposite:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div id="show-mobile" class="span6">Your Beautiful Code For Mobile Only</div>
</div>


@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {


    #show-mobile {

        display:none;

    }


}


@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {

    #show-mobile {

        display:block;

    }

    #remove-mobile {

        display:none;

    }

}
```

Comment: This could have been achieved more elegantly - and with valid HTML code - using the Bootstrap classes `hidden-phone` and `hidden-desktop`. But duplicating the HTML code for every media is not what I wanted to do.

Comment: If done right, you need to only write two headers.  One for mobile and tablets and one for desktops.  At least, that is my approach.  If you do find something better, please update your question with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the simplest of solutions but I've found it suits my needs

https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/mixins.less#L572

If you dive into the source for bootstraps grid, it's relatively easy to pull out the less code used to generate the span[1-12] system.

So I just pulled out the basics and put them in my own file with a different selector. So now, when I want to use span's that don't wrap I just use .naps[1-12] (Span spelt backwards).

The responsive CSS looks for .span[1-12] selectors so it ignores my .naps elements.

It's not elegant, and it's not particularly scalable. It does work though :-/